# get json from google map api and not work in php, bad charater encoding

Tags: php, json, character-encoding

I would like to print how I can go from "A" city to "B" city. I use PHP and Google Maps API. I can do it already but when the result is printed, the charater encoding isn't right.

If I set `GET` param like this: `origin=Cegléd` then Google Maps API won't work, but if I set it like this: `origin=Cegled` then Google Maps API works. I set utf-8 character encoding so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
<?php

    header ('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

    $a="---";
    $origin=$_GET['origin'];
    $destination=$_GET['destination'];

    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=";
    $url = $url . $origin;
    $url = $url . "&destination=";
    $url = $url . $destination;
    $url=  $url . "&language=hu-HU&ie=utf8";

    echo $url;
    echo $a;

    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode(utf8_encode($json),true);

    echo $data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['text'];
    echo $a;
    echo $data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['distance']['value'];
    echo $a;
    echo '
         ';
    $inc=1;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps']);$i++){

        $subject = $data['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][$i]['html_instructions'];
        $search1 = '<b>';
        $search2 = '</b>';
        $trimmed = str_replace($search1, '', $subject);
        $result =  str_replace($search2, '', $trimmed);


        echo $inc .". lépés:" . $result;
        echo '
             ----';
        echo $a;
        $inc++;
    }

?>
```

This code doesn't display the right charaters. I haven't got any idea why.

[This example](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Szeged&destination=Budapest&language=hu-HU&ie=utf8---174) displays:

> km---173860--- 1. l�p�s:Haladjon tovÃ¡bb Ã©szaknyugat felÃ© itt: Gogol u., Londoni krt. irÃ¡nyÃ¡ba -------2. l�p�s:Forduljon jobbra az 1. keresztutcÃ¡nÃ¡l erre rÃ¡tÃ©rve: Londoni krt. -------3. l�p�s:Folytassa az utat erre: Mars tÃ©r -------4. l�p�s:Folytassa az utat erre: PÃ¡rizsi krt. -------5. l�p�s:Folytassa az utat erre: Berlini krt./43. Ãºt -------6. l�p�s:Forduljon balra, a kÃ¶vetkezÅ Ãºtra:

Comment: So what *is* it displaying? Why are you throwing in a `utf8_encode` there? There's no good reason for it and may actually be your problem.

Comment: Display this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Szeged&destination=Budapest&language=hu-HU&ie=utf8---174 km---173860---
   1. l�p�s:Haladjon tovÃ¡bb Ã©szaknyugat felÃ© itt: Gogol u., Londoni krt. irÃ¡nyÃ¡ba
    -------2. l�p�s:Forduljon jobbra az 1. keresztutcÃ¡nÃ¡l erre rÃ¡tÃ©rve: Londoni krt.
    -------3. l�p�s:Folytassa az utat erre: Mars tÃ©r
    -------4. l�p�s:Folytassa az utat erre: PÃ¡rizsi krt.
    -------5. l�p�s:Folytassa az utat erre: Berlini krt./43. Ãºt
    -------6. l�p�s:Forduljon balra, a kÃ¶vetkezÅ Ãºtra:

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response from Google is probably encoded in UTF-8 already. You should skip the `utf8_encode()` call in:

```
$data = json_decode(utf8_encode($json),true);
```

Encoding UTF-8 data twice typically results in extra `Â`, `Ã` and other similar characters.